# How to use Javascriptexecutor for entering text in an element which does not have Id as a locator?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to enter text in an Textbox which does not take the input through SendKeys. I proceeded with using Javascriptexecutor to enter the text and succeeded. Now there are a few fields in which there is no Id that can be selected as a locator so I need to locate them with Xpath. I would like to know how can we locate the element by xpath in Javascriptexecutor and pass the values to it.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('value').value='1611 
Dragons';");
```

I need an approach where I can use it something like:

```
document.getElementByXpath("Xpath Here").value='xyz';");
```

Please feel free to guide me to a Doc/answer if it documented somewhere before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code, it would solve your problem:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter the xpath here"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='enter the value here';", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at document.evaluate.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  xpathExpression,
  contextNode,
  namespaceResolver,
  resultType,
  result
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter text within a *textbox* identified through an *xpath* you can use the following notation:

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("document.evaluate(xpathExpresion, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan for your input. Unfortunately it did not solved my problem. On execution it gave me an exception unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input